Hide secondary Y axis when trace is on "legendonly"
I have an R Shiny app in which I am rendering a plotly plot with several traces. One of those traces uses a secondary Y axis on the right of the plot:
library(plotly)
data(mtcars)

ui <- fluidPage( plotlyOutput("scatterPlot"))
server <- function(input, output) {
  
  ay <- list(overlaying = "y", side = "right", title = "Hide me please", automargin = TRUE)
  
  output$scatterPlot <- renderPlotly({
    p <- plot_ly(type = "scatter", mode = "markers") %>% 
      add_trace(data = mtcars, x = ~mpg, y = ~hp) %>%
      add_trace(data = mtcars, x = ~mpg, y = ~wt, yaxis = "y2") %>% 
      layout(legend = list(orientation = "v"),
             yaxis2 = ay)
    
    return(p)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)

Desired Result: When toggling the second trace on and off via clicking on the legend entry, the plot should update and the secondary axis should be toggled off/on accordingly
After some research, I stumbled across this post. I only have very basic JS knowledge but using this I managed to create values which I can observe :
js <- "function(el, x){
    el.on('plotly_legendclick', function(evtData) {
    Shiny.setInputValue('trace', evtData.curveNumber);
    });


    el.on('plotly_restyle', function(evtData) {
    Shiny.setInputValue('visibility', evtData[0].visible);
    });
  }"

In server.R:
p %>% onRender(js)

This way I know which trace (input$trace) has which visibility (input$visibility).
Is there a way to dynamically toggle the secondary axis in the rendered plot in the Shiny app on and off based on these values in R?

You could have a look at plotlyProxy (using plotlyProxyInvoke with method = "relayout" (see also here on Plotly.relayout)).

Thank you very much, this solved my problem! Will post the working code as an answer. I must admit, the documentation for these proxy functions is really difficult and patchy (and I'm finding little to no tutorials) if you aren't already a pro in plotly.js

After the first comment by Jan, I was able to solve this.
The following code produces a plot in which the secondary axis gets removed if the second trace is deselected in the legend.
library(plotly)
library(shiny)
library(htmlwidgets)
data(mtcars)

ui <- fluidPage(plotlyOutput("scatterPlot"))

js <- "function(el, x){
    el.on('plotly_legendclick', function(evtData) {
    Shiny.setInputValue('trace', evtData.curveNumber);
    });


    el.on('plotly_restyle', function(evtData) {
    Shiny.setInputValue('visibility', evtData[0].visible);
    });
  }"

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  # defining secondary axis
  ay <- list(overlaying = "y",
             side = "right",
             title = "Hide me please",
             automargin = TRUE)

  # render the plot with the JS code from above
  output$scatterPlot <- renderPlotly({
    p <- plot_ly(type = "scatter", mode = "markers") %>%
      add_trace(data = mtcars, x = ~mpg, y = ~hp) %>%
      add_trace(data = mtcars, x = ~mpg, y = ~wt, yaxis = "y2") %>%
      layout(legend = list(orientation = "v"),
             yaxis2 = ay)

    p <- p %>% onRender(js)

  })

  # observe the two values from the JS code, use plotlyproxy to toggle axis when condition met
  observeEvent({
                input$trace
                input$visibility
               },
               {
                 if (input$trace == 2) {
                   # TRUE if TRUE, FALSE if "legendonly"
                   ay[["visible"]] <- input$visibility == TRUE
                   plotlyProxy("scatterPlot", session) %>%
                     plotlyProxyInvoke("relayout", list(yaxis2 = ay))
                 }
               })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)



Below please find a JS-only approach based on my earlier answer here avoiding the plotlyProxy-detour, which should be faster:
library(plotly)
library(shiny)
library(htmlwidgets)
data(mtcars)

trace_name <- "hide_me"

ui <- fluidPage(plotlyOutput("scatterPlot"))

jsCode <- "function(el, x, data){
    var id = el.getAttribute('id');
    var gd = document.getElementById(id);
    el.on('plotly_restyle', function(evtData) {
      function setAxisVisibility(trace, traceindex) {
        if (trace.name === data.trace_name){
          if (trace.visible === true){
            Plotly.relayout(gd, 'yaxis2.visible', true);
          } else {
            Plotly.relayout(gd, 'yaxis2.visible', false);
          }
        }
      }
      el._fullData.forEach(setAxisVisibility);
    });
  }"

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  # defining secondary axis
  ay <- list(overlaying = "y",
             side = "right",
             title = "Hide me please",
             automargin = TRUE)
  
  # render the plot with the JS code from above
  output$scatterPlot <- renderPlotly({
    p <- plot_ly(type = "scatter", mode = "markers") %>%
      add_trace(data = mtcars, x = ~mpg, y = ~hp) %>%
      add_trace(name = trace_name, data = mtcars, x = ~mpg, y = ~wt, yaxis = "y2") %>%
      layout(legend = list(orientation = "v"),
             yaxis2 = ay)
    
    p <- p %>% onRender(jsCode, data = list(trace_name = trace_name))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)

